# How to completely mute Chrome, permanently?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, mute

Not individual tabs, and not just until I close it.

How can make sure that Chrome never emits another sound, ever?

On Windows 10

Comment: What operating system? On Windows you can use the audio mixer to adjust the volume (and mute) specific applications.

Comment: Widows it is. Sorry for not stating so. Feel free to post an answer with details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can use the Volume Mixer to adjust the volume of specific applications.

You can access it my right-clicking the speaker icon in your taskbar and selecting volume mixer. From there you should have a left-right scrolling list of applications where you can control their individual volumes.

It seems that this behaviour might have [changed in recent versions](https://www.techspot.com/news/77251-microsoft-replacing-windows-10-volume-mixer.html) of Windows and it will instead take you to the control panel where you can make changes.

Alternatively you can run the old mixer with <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and running `sndvol.exe`.

Comment: Perfect! I have been looking for this for so long. I can confirm that this works, and that when I close, then re-open Chrome, it is still muted. Thanx a 1,000,000

Comment: @Mawg you are very welcome